# PHP set values from database

Tags: php, postgresql, get, set

I am new and still lerning php and Im trying to set values that Im retrieving from postgresql database, but Im having problems with my code that i cant figure out and I hope someone here can help me. :)

This is the code:

```
public function __construct($username, $password)
{
    $config = new Config();
    $dbconn = pg_connect($config->getDbDsn()); // getDbDsn contains all the information that is needed to connect to the database.
    $query = "SELECT username, password, id FROM user.member WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);

    $db = pg_fetch_all($result);


    if($db)
    {
        foreach($db as $d)
        {
            if( $d['username'] == $username && $d['password'] == $password)
            {
                $this->verified = true;
                $this->id = $d['id']; //save id does not work
                $this->user = $d['username']; // save username does not work

            }
            else
            {
                $this->verified = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->verified = false;
    }
}
```

Okay, this is what im trying to do. First im asking the database to give me the informationen from the table, that is a match to my users username and password. I am using a bool (verified) to verify the user. That works fine. But then, when Im trying to set the values of username and id for my user, that is impossible. If im creating a set_val-function (just to test my code, to try to find my error):

```
private $a = "";
private function set_val($data){ $this->a = $data; }
```

and I use that function to set value, in my construct-function:

```
$this->set_val('hello');
```

that works  fine, until I put that function in my if($db)-statment, then it doesnt work anymore. (it works fine if I put it outside my if($db)-statement, like directly under $db = pg_fetch_all($result);).

```
$db = pg_fetch_all($result);

$this->set_val('hello'); // This works fine 

if($db)
{ 
   $this->set_val('hello'); // This does not work at all

    foreach($db as $d)
         $this->set_val('hello'); // And not this
}
```

For my get_val I have this code:

```
public function get_val(){
    return $this->a;
}
```

(I also have the same get-functions for id and username)

And here Im trying to echo my value, which works fine, if I put the set_val-function outside my if-statement (and foreach-statement):

```
public function echo_val(){
     echo $this->get_val();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `$db` is maybe falsy and therefore the inner part of the if is never evauated?

Comment: How can I do that in a proper way? 

The code works fine in that way that I can log in to the site with username and password, so I hope (guess) that $db is true, but Im not sure. I cant find out how to debug php like im debugging C++. Is it possible?

Comment: Step debugging is possible and usually done via the php-xdebug extension and a debugger client (most PHP IDEs have one, but there are standalone debuggers as well). Apart from that you could simply try to var_dump or error_log the type of $db for a quick check.

Comment: Okay, I changed my code to check if $db is true, and you are right, its not true. That makes me confused because I can log in to the site with my code, so why is $db not true? I mean, if I delete the row with $this->verified = true (in the if( $d['username']...)-statement), I cant log in to the site. :o

Comment: That is indeed confusing :o 

Do you do that with different user/pw combinations? $db should only be true-ish if the user was actually found, so maybe it's just that? You tried with non existing user?

Comment: I have two users and I can log in with both user names. If I try to log in with a non existing user, I get my "wrong username or password"-message. Something is very wrong with my code. ;)

Comment: It's really not clear to me what is wrong though. :D There is a bunch of things I personally would do differently, but the `set_val()` should work inside and outside of that if just fine. Maybe post the full class? Or does it only have the constructor?